# Proving that kernels are closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, linear-algebra

We have to show that given k_1 and k_2 are both kernels, the sum k_1 + 2*k_2 is a kernel as well.
I am attempting to show this by using Mercer's theorem:

$k(x,y) = <a(x),a(y)>$.

Showing that $2*k_2$ is also a kernel seems quite straightforward to me:

If $k_2(x,y) = <b(x),b(y)>$

Then $2*k_2(x,y) = 2*\sum{_j} (b_j(x),b_j(y)) = \sum{_j} 2*(b_j(x),b_j(y)) =
\sum{_j} (b_j(2*x),b_j(y))$, which, by definition, is also a kernel.

I get stuck however in the next step. So we want to show that we can reformulate the sum of the kernels as a scalar product as well. We start with (I am leaving the 2* out for simplicity):

$\sum_{i}a_i(x)a_i(y) + \sum_{j}b_j(x)b_j(y)$ - how however can I reformulate this to arrive at $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(a_i(x)b_j(x))(a_i(y)b_j(y))$...?

Comment: If you start with a particular definition of "kernel", such as ["a symmetric positive-definite operator,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel#Definition) then this result is immediate (and trivial).  You must therefore be using some other definition--but what would it be?

Comment: Well, Mercer's, as I am saying...or do you mean something else?

Comment: You might be overthinking this: you have greatly complicated the solution by reaching out to a deep theorem for your characterization of a kernel.  If you would begin with the *definition* of a kernel, which is simple and elementary, I believe you would quickly discover the simple and elementary proof that any positive linear combination of kernels is a kernel.

Comment: oooh...quite trivial indeed (however not sure if that will be how our official solutions look like). So I guess you mean the following: Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be positive-definite matrices, then by definition for a $\vec(x)$, x not the nullvector: $x^TK_1x>0, xK_2x^T>0$, hence $xK_1x^T+xK_2x^T>0$ and rewriting it we have $x^T(K_1+K_2)x$ > 0 (the x are vectors..sorry for sloppiness). Yes? Btw also found a proof based on Mercer's, quite elegant, but as you say waaay more complicated, here page 5 http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-07/lectures/kernels/kernels.pdf

Comment: Yes--and the same approach,without any change at all, works for arbitrary kernels (positive-definite linear operators on Hilbert spaces), not just matrices.

Comment: Thx. Btw, I often read that kernels have to be i. Positive semi-definite ii. symmetric. But is ii. not given when we can show that i. is given?

Comment: One finds some confusion over this.  Positive-(semi)definiteness is really a property of a *quadratic form.*  Although any square matrix represents a quadratic form, that same form corresponds to many such matrices--but only to one symmetric matrix.  (Specifically, the symmetric matrix $(A+A^\prime)/2$ represents the  same quadratic form as $A$, at least over fields of characteristic not equal to $2$.) Thus, in any discussion of definiteness of operators it is usually implicitly assumed they are symmetric.