# Sum of two kernel is also a kernel, how can we prove that?

Tags: kernel-trick

Suppose that k(·, ·) and k 0 (·, ·) are kernels. Prove that l(·, ·) where l(x, y) = k(x, y) + k0 (x, y) is also a kernel.

I am having trouble proving this, can you help?

Comment: You can find some hints at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294400/proving-that-kernels-are-closed-under-addition-and-scalar-multiplication

Comment: I did not understand much.. I will try though, thanks!

Comment: "Kernel" is an overloaded term in math and statistics, so beware.  The comment thread suggests it is meant in the sense of the duplicate.

Comment: add definition of kernel you are using